# Increase 1 UITableViewCell separator height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` in which I'm trying to make 1 `cells` separators height larger than the rest. I tried the following:

```
UIView* separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 2)];
separator.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:separator];
```

That works, but results in the following look:

[image]

The separator line for all the `cells` are set to red. In the picture above, you can see the red above the black. How can I remove the red for that cell?

I tried: `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;` and that didn't do anything.

Comment: Please go through below link you will get the solution in best way...!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711612/how-to-change-separator-height-in-uitableview-swift-3/45893185#45893185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use table view separator style property to remove default separator,

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

This will remove default separator and you can use your own. Make sure that you remove custom separators properly as cell view is reused.

Comment: "Make sure that you remove custom separators properly as cell view is reused" Good advice.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot draw your own separator *and* use the built-in separators - well, you can, but you will see both of them, as you have clearly shown. If you are going to draw your own separator, tell the cell or table view not to supply separators at all.

Comment: How can I set 1 cell not to have a separator?

Comment: You probably can't. Having decided to take charge of drawing the separator for one cell, you must probably just bite the bullet and draw the separators for all of them. That is what I have always done.

Answer (score 0):

first of all remove the default  UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle to none as below..

```
[tableview setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

and after that use your own separator..