# How to change separator height in UITableView Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, list-separator

Although there a few answers already on this topic. None of them cover Swift 3 and they are from a long time ago. What is currently the best way to change the separator height in a UITableView in Swift 3?

Comment: You can use a cell as separator and set separatorCell height. Just like cell-separatorCelll-cell-...

Comment: check the value of separatorInset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated for Swift 3:

If you want to change the height of the UITableView separator, use the code below.
You should add it to the UITableViewCell method `awakeFromNib()` to avoid re-creation.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    let mScreenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let mSeparatorHeight = CGFloat(3.0) // Change height of speatator as you want
    let mAddSeparator = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - mSeparatorHeight, width: mScreenSize.width, height: mSeparatorHeight))
    mAddSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown // Change backgroundColor of separator
    self.addSubview(mAddSeparator)
}
```

Comment: hey - this actually places a UIView inside the cell, giving the appearance of a thicker separator, but in reality it is just taking up space inside the cell. Is there a way to really increase the thickness of the separator?

Comment: @richc You can create a custom cell in which you can create a view which will contain all the cell components and this view will be smaller than the content view of the whole custom cell. The separator height can be set with the help of constraints in the custom cell.

Comment: This is not changing the separator height instead it is inserting another view in the cell. This is not the right answer

Answer (score 3):

This is a correct way to do this.

First, in your ViewController you should set (tableView.separatorStyle = .none)

```
import UIKit 

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
   }

}
```

Second, in your TableViewCell class your should create a separatorView.
And don't forget to inherit TableViewCell class for your cell.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   let separator = UIView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    separator.backgroundColor = .black
    contentView.addSubview(separator)
}
   override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()

      //Your separatorLineHeight with scalefactor 
      let separatorLineHeight: CGFloat = 1/UIScreen.main.scale

      separator.frame = CGRect(x: self.contentView.frame.origin.x, 
                               y: self.contentView.frame.size.height - separatorLineHeight,
                           width: self.contentView.frame.size.width,
                          height: separatorLineHeight)
   }

}
```

Finally, you've got a thin separator line and, of course, you can increase this value what do you like.

Comment: Pls, comment here, if someone need an Objective-C version

Comment: `laytouSubviews()` method is calling multiple times so UIView as separator will be created multiple times. That's not very good and efficient.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll correct this code. It Was so long time ago :)

Answer (score 0):

For Those who want to do it using autolayout here is the code

```
var additionalSeparator:UIView = UIView()
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.createSeparator()
    }
    func createSeparator() {

        self.additionalSeparator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.additionalSeparator)
    }
    func setConstraintForSeparator() {
        self.additionalSeparator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: self.separatorInset.left).isActive = true
        self.additionalSeparator.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -self.separatorInset.right).isActive = true
        self.additionalSeparator.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.additionalSeparator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
        self.additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.greyishBrown
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this Swift 3:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as! yourTableViewCell

    let viewSeparatorLine = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 5.0, width: cell.contentView.frame.size.width, height: 5))
    viewSeparatorLine.backgroundColor = .red
    cell.contentView.addSubview(viewSeparatorLine)
    return cell
}
```